# esp8266 occasional resets when controlled relay is energized

Tags: relay, esp8266, reset

I am having trouble with a circuit that I have designed for an esp8266, that controls 4 relays.
The MCU is flashed with esphome, and occasionally resets itself, after turning on one of the relays.
I thought one of the following could occur:

1. Power peak when relay is energized drops voltage and the MCU resets itself. I have a 470uf elco right next to the chip between 3.3V and GND so that should be enough buffer.
2. Some kind of interference coming in from the pump that is on the load side of the relay, and runs from 230V mains, but even without load, MCU sometimes restarts. Without load MCU seems to be more stable though, and the occasional restarts are less frequent.

PS is HLK PM-01, Relays are: SDT-S-103DMR,000, and regulator is: REG1117-3.3/2K5.
[image: Schematics of the board]

Comment: An Omron G6L-1P 3.3 version draws 60mA when its coil is energised. The 3.3V regulator has a maximum current output of 0.8 to 1 A, and the AC-DC power module's output current limit is 0.6A. So the 3.3V supply voltage shouldn't drop easily with a 60mA load step. So I don't think the problem is a sag caused by a relay. You should use a scope to see the 3.3V supply rail when a coil is energised.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a scope. You are right, I did the math too, and it should have worked.

Comment: From relay [datasheet](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1461267-1.datasheet.pdf) it is supposed to draw 200mA. Why use 3V3 relay when you have 5V available?

Comment: 5V relays may have been used as well. DS says coil is rated to 540mW, which should be around 160mA. Even with that, the circuit is well within the power supply's rated output, as the relays are interlocked and there is only one active at a time.

Comment: put the cap on the input of the 3.3v regulator instead of the output. it holds a lot more energy that way. you might raise the 3.3v a diode drop and put a diode in front of the 32's vcc (and cap), giving it a "private" 3.3v pool that the relay surge cannot pull down.